# How to pass data from one viewcontroller to another viewcontroller which is got in json and need to be set in a tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Here is my code:

```
public func getMethod() -> Array<Any>{
    var array = [Any]()
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let aURL = URL(string: baseUrl+month)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: aURL)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("Bearer \(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Actoken)!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
            array = [json]
            print(array)
            print(json)
        } catch {
            print("Could not serialise")
        }

    })
    print(array)
    task.resume()

    return array
}
```

The result I get from JSON is:

```
{
    {
        item = 1,
        name = "Abc"
    },
    {
        item = 1,
        name = "Def"
    }
}
```

But when I try to return in another view controller it is returning null value.
If not in this way how can I proceed.
I need to insert the derived json into table view.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `completion` for any asynchronous operation, So your code should look like,

```
class classA {

public func getMethod(completion: @escaping (_ resultArray: [Any])->()) {
        var array = [Any]()
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let aURL = URL(string: baseUrl+month)!
        var request = URLRequest(url: aURL)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("Bearer \(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: Actoken)!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
                array = [json]
                completion(array)
            }
            catch {
                print("Could not serialise")
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

//Caller should be like

```
let yourClass = classA()
yourClass.getMethod { [weak self] (resultArr) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let classB = ClassB()
        classB.resultArray = resultArr
        self?.navigationController.pushViewController(classB, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

once it's pushed to classB with result array, you can parse the JSON response and populate on the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a closure into the getMethod that will be executed when the response is received. Inside the closure, update the tableview's datasource with the json, and reloadData.

```
public func getMethod(completion: (yourCustomType)->() ) {

    ...

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, 
                   completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONDecoder.decode(yourCustomType.self, data)
                completion(json)
            }catch {
                    ...
            }
        }

   })

   task.resume()
}

getMethod() { (responseData: YourCustomType) in
    tableviewDatasource = responseData
    DispatchQueue.main.async{ 
        self.tableview.reloadData
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how asynchronous programming works.

You are making an async call (the `session.dataTask` call) and expecting to return the results synchronously.  Your calling function is reading the result likely before the network call has finished.  You should use a closure (completion block) instead.

Here's some simple playground code that demonstrates the async model:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let Actoken = "SOMETHING"

public func getMethod(baseUrl:String, month:String, completion:@escaping (Array<Any>?)->()){

    var array = [Any]()
    let session = URLSession.shared
    guard let aURL = URL(string: baseUrl+month) else {
        print("invalid url")
        completion(nil)
        return
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: aURL)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        do {
            if let data = data {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
                array = [json]
                completion(array)
            } else {
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("Could not serialise")
            completion(nil)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}

// here's how you call it from the view controller
getMethod(baseUrl: "https://mobilesecurity.win/sample.json", month: "") { array in
    if let array = array {
        print(array)
    } else {
        print("array was nil")
    }
}
```